# How to Link updated APK of alpha test to production apk

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I  have uploaded one APK in production mode. Now, i have updated one new APK with changes in alpha testing and would like to link this new apk to production mode. In "What's New" section added information change immediately.But, while user go for download the old production APK downloaded and APK link not change with new APK.

I have set new alpha APK version higher than old one.

Answer (score 1):

Alpha apps are intended for internal testing and not to be seen by public users, if you want to access the alpha apps you need to add the email address used to open Play Store in the internal testers in google play console as show in the below image

[image]

in the image above it shows the link that the testers should use to access the alpha apps on Google Play

**However** in case you are asking how you can move the alpha app to the production track so it can be accessed by all users on Google Play?

When you open the alpha track, then you open the release you have created, on top of the card that contains the release information you'll find a buttons says "Release To Production"

When you click on it will move the alpha release to production in which you want to fill the required fields and Review->Save

Let me know if you need any further help with that

Comment: I already knew all about this. I have already one apk at production mode. Now I uploaded new apk with higher version code in alpha testing. It updates "What's New" information immediately  but it showing old version APK on play store.why is this happen?

Comment: Did you release it to production? That doesn't make sense because if you rolled out the release on production it should update everything.

Comment: No already one apk in production. Now I have apk with new modules and changes so I uploaded apk with higher version code in alpha testing but it still shows old production apk

Comment: thats why, because it is in alpha track, you have to "Release To Production" in order to update the APK on google play

Comment: but I dont want to release this apk to live. I only want to share with some specific users via alpha testing. Please guide me if I did anything wrong. waiting for your reply

Comment: then as shown in the image above, you need to add user's email in which you would like to give them access to the alpha app using "Manage Testers" and there you add their emails, after that you give them the link as shown in image above "op-in url" it'll redirect them to a page were it tells them that your going to testing app, when they click on "become a tester" it redirects them to the app store where new APK shows (Only for them)... hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone can see the Alpha apps. Make sure to check your alpha delivery settings (who can see alpha versions and download them).

Comment: How to set settings? and will it affect immediately or it will take some time fro refresh on play store?